# Trash doesn't clean

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon

When I deleted friles to my Trash, I can not empty the bin.
I need to restart my desktop in order to empty it.
What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the case of deleted files from the USB drive that was later unmounted. The Trash is empty but the icon is always showing it's full. At least that's what is happening to me sometimes. I wouldn't worry.